# how to check some id exist in a variable with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i create a function with php which give me back this data from ajax

```
> Object {0: "<div class="message_text" id="297"><div
> class="use…-$('.messages').prop('clientHeight'))</div></div>", 1:
> "<div class="message_text" id="296"><div class="use…/div><div
> class="users_message">jkhj'</div></div>", 2: "<div
> class="message_text" id="295"><div class="use…></div><div
> class="users_message">asd</div></div>", finish: "<div
> id="finish"></div>"}
```

now i need to check last message_text id to see if its equal to some value but i dont know how to search in this variable for some id?
thanks in advance

**EDIT**

i can seperate them with each function and search between them but i dont know how to search between them?

```
$.each(data,function(key,value){
console.log(value);
});
```

which value is

```
> <div class="message_text" id="297"><div
> class="users_messsage_image"><a href="../profile.php?id=1"><img
> src="../album/images/thumbs/2013/5/1/1/a8a73760-8c3d-4180-bcca-772a0ed48873.jpg"
> width="40" height="40" /></a></div><div
> class="users_message">hello</div></div>
```

Comment: That data looks very broken to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery do

```
$(object[0]).find('#the_id')
```

which will return all objects with that id.

Comment: ..which should only be one.

Comment: @Zenith - that is irrelevant...

Comment: @Zenith - yes I could add .length == 1, but I think you should have faith that the OP is not 5